# Auto orientation in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation

I have used `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` to get notified of landscape and potrait mode. In my project I'm required to change the positions of `UIControls` placed on the `UIView` accordingly. Do I have to change the frame size manually for each `UIControl`, as this is hectic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view controller you should implement method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

This method should return `YES` for supported orientations.

If you want your subviews to resize and reposition automatically then you should set appropriate property `autoresizingMask` of that views. For example:

```
blackView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
                                 UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Comment: Does here autoresizingMask means i can shrink or zoom subview, that is flexible relative to the superview change? But in my project i have been given fixed position to each uicontrol according to the type of orientation mode. Can i use autoresizingMask to change the origin of the uicontrols.

Comment: Values `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` will help you to autoresize your view accordingly to its superview. Other values will help you to change the origin of view in superview. Try to play with them... Also you can open IB -> Pick View -> Utilities -> Size Inspector -> Autoresizing.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to use the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation... method but you need to do a little more before it will work properly.  First of all, you will need two xib files, one for a landscape orientation and one for a portrait orientation.  You will then need to use your function like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    //prepare for a Landscape view
    }
else{
    //prepare for a portrait view
    }
    return YES;
}
```

As for preparing for landscape or portrait views, using autoresizing can work but you may need to have totally seperate xibs.  I could not find a way to change the xib within the active view controller, so I would suggest making a seperate instance of your view controller.  Example:

When you present your first instance of the viewController, present it with the portrait xib.  You may also need a boolean to keep track of the current xib.  Then have this code implemented:

```
/*Assuming you are using a viewcontroller called viewController, and you have a boolean called xibPortrait.
You have presented this view controller using the portrait xib.
You also have a landscape xib, Landscape.xib
*/

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if ((interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) && xibPortrait){
        xibPortrait = FALSE;
        viewController *Land = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Landscape" bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:Land animated:NO];
        [Land release];
    }
else if(!xibPortrait){
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    xibPortrait = TRUE;
    }
return YES;
}


//This should work but if you can, you should try to use Autoresizing.
```

EDIT:
I also found this which someone posted on one of my questions.  It may help your app work more efficiently than using my method above:
http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/ipad-development-101-orientation/

Comment: Two separate view controllers to different screen positions? Bad idea... Try to calculate memory alloc+free if user will turn your app and will rotate device 10x times...

Comment: Idk, I could not find a better way to change xibs when changing orientation.  I have not dealt with this in my own apps yet, I only have to change between landscape orientations and that is much, much simpler because the view will look the same, just viewed from the other side.  Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: You should do this programmatically. To allocate new memory when you can just change positions is bad choise.

Comment: I was considering the case in which you need to do more than change positions.  I do not know how likely this case is because I have not made an app which involves switching between portrait and landscape modes.